# Can an F-test be used in a regression that is quadratic, or can it only be used in a linear regression model?

Tags: econometrics

My regression I'm testing is quadratic but everything I've read about using F-tests state that it is used in a linear regression model.

Comment: Your regression is quadratic, like (A) $Y = (\alpha + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2)^2 + \epsilon$ or (B)  $Y = \alpha + \beta_1 X_1 + \gamma_1 X_1^2 + \beta_2 X_2  + \gamma_2 X_2^2 + \epsilon$?

Comment: @kurtosis it is like (B).

Comment: Ah. Then it is a linear model. Model A is quadratic in the terms while model B is linear in the terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your model is like
$$
Y = \alpha + \beta_1 X_1 + \gamma_1 X_1^2 + \beta_2 X_2 + \gamma_2 X_2^2 + \epsilon,
$$
it is still a linear model -- because it is linear in the terms. ("Linear" refers to the terms like $X_1$ and $X_1^2$ being linearly combined.)

You can use an $F$-test for your model.